# How to solve TeamCity GitVersion infinte loop error?

Tags: git, teamcity, gitversion

I have strange error with GitVersion procedure in TeamCity. It fall into infinte loop consisting of code below.

The branch0 is a parent for branch1 and branch2.
I am trying to deploy branch2 and there is an error related to branch1 displayed, where it should not have any connection to it at all.

Also I am curious what is the difference betwen 'develop' and 'origin/develop' in this context, as to me they both should be the same remote branch, shouldn't they?

I suspect there might be some issue with the way the branches relate to each other, but couldn't really figure it out. The curious part is that when i delete branch1, then I can easily deploy branch0 and branch2. Once I create the branch1 again from branch0, then yet again it fails.

````
Falling back to branch1 branch config
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]             INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:16] No branch configuration found for branch branch1, falling back to default configuration
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]             INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:16] Begin: Attempting to inherit branch configuration from parent branch
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:16] HEAD is merge commit, this is likely a pull request using master as base
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] Begin: Finding branch source of 'master'
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] Multiple source branches have been found, picking the first one (develop).
[15:07:52][Step 1/1] This may result in incorrect commit counting.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1] Options were:
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]  develop, origin/develop
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] End: Finding branch source of 'master' (Took: 1.00ms)
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] Begin: Getting branches containing the commit 'hash1'.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] Trying to find direct branches.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] No direct branches found, searching through tracked branches.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:17] Searching for commits reachable from 'develop'.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:20] The branch 'develop' has a matching commit.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:20] Searching for commits reachable from 'origin/develop'.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:24] The branch 'origin/develop' has a matching commit.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:24] End: Getting branches containing the commit 'hash1'. (Took: 68.00ms)
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:24] Begin: Getting branches containing the commit 'hash2'.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:24] Trying to find direct branches.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:24] No direct branches found, searching through tracked branches.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:24] Searching for commits reachable from 'develop'.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:27] The branch 'develop' has a matching commit.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:27] Searching for commits reachable from 'origin/develop'.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]                 INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:30] The branch 'origin/develop' has a matching commit.
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:30] End: Getting branches containing the commit 'hash1'. (Took: 66.00ms)
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               INFO [05/25/20 15:07:52:30] Found possible parent branches: 
[15:07:52][Step 1/1]               WARN [05/25/20 15:07:52:30] Failed to inherit Increment branch configuration, no branches found.```
````

Comment: Have you configured [`teamcity.git.fetchAllHeads=true`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/git.html#Git-GeneralSettings) in TeamCity? Which version of GitVersion is this?

Comment: This setting is set to true and it is GitVersion3

Comment: Then I would recommend upgrading GitVersion, as version 3 is many years old. GitVersion is currently on version 5.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error it seems like the best solution here was to update the ignore timestamp for git commits in the GitVersionConfig.yaml file